# How to identify or give a meaning to the cluster membership in a hierarchical clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I know clustering is a type of unsupervised learning problem, however when Kmean clustering is used one can sort the membership based on the cluster centers.
For example consider the cluster membership to be:

```
1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1
```

You can look at the mean of each cluster and say for example cluster 2 has larger mean and therefore corresponds to this group of things. However I am wondering what information one can obtain from hierarchical clustering since there is no notion of cluster mean or center?

Therefore how do you give any meaning to the cluster membership how can draw a conclusion in which what is cluster 2 corresponds to ?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have numeric data, you can still do the same. In fact, Ward linkage is closely related to kmeans.

However, you may want to use some more advanced methods than looking at the mean only. For example, Fishers LDA takes variance into account, and with non-numerical values it may be meaningful to identify relevant features and values by analyzing, for example, a random forest.

With the search function you will likely find discussion of further ways of analyzing clusters.

Comment: Thanks. I have numeric data. May I know how to access information with Ward linkage. I am using R and I am using Ward as well. However after using hclust with Ward linkage then I get object like: cluster method: Ward-D2 and number of samples. How can I find some information about clusters in any language ?

Comment: I can look at the height or the merge order but I do not know what to get from them. It is important to mention that my original data is  a time series.

Comment: You will have to compute the mean yourself, because it's not explicitly used by the algorithm. Computing the mean is, however, not difficult.

Comment: Ward linkage expects squared Euclidean distances, which is commonly defined on fixed length vectors. If your time series have varying length, then Ward linkage is probably not sound to use, not is the meannas representative. You'll have to decide upon a different choice of cluster representatives. For example, you could be using MiniMax clustering or medoids.

Answer (score 0):

> However I am wondering what information one can obtain from hierarchical clustering since there is no notion of cluster mean or center?

If you are searching for charaterics KPI's of a cluster, you will get disappointed. There is no 1-dimensional KPI which will be typicall for a cluster. Imagen this data:

```
Index Weight Height
1       1      1
2       1      2
3       2      10
4       1      20
```

and you assign two clusters to it, you probably get:

```
Cluster1: (1,2)
Cluster2: (3,4)
```

The mean of height and weight for this clusters are:

```
Weight: (1,1.5)
Height: (1.5, 15)
```

So it does not help you to interpret something. The original values are not really reflected in a 1-dimensional value.

Clusters are mainly used to (pre-) group data to define one action for the full cluster group.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> However I am wondering what information one can obtain from
>   hierarchical clustering since there is no notion of cluster mean or
>   center?

I'm not sure where you are getting the idea that there is "no notion" of this in hierarchical clustering. There is just as much notion of this in hierarchical clustering as in k means -- the difference is in how the clusters are obtained, not what they mean.

So, you can examine the clusters in any way that you like in order to assign meaning to them. Certainly you can look at the means and sds of all the variables in each cluster. You can also use whatever other methods you find useful.

Comment: May I know how to access these information in any programming language or even high level. I personally use R. However if you mean to find the average of elements in the same cluster then my  data is a time series with different length (I do not know how to find the mean and standard deviation). I created an appropriate distance matrix then I use a hierarchical clustering with ward linkage

Comment: I can look at the height or merge order of my clusters but I do not know what to get from them

Comment: The cluster membership for each subject is available in R. I don't know the exact syntax, but you can look at the help files.